# Unworking SET in a FOR /L in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, set

pCan anyone explain why SET is not doing anything in the following code?:

```
ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%b IN (-1,1,1) DO (
SET /A _lat=%%b
ECHO variable lat: %_lat%
ECHO variable b: %%b
ECHO:
)
```

output:

```
variable lat:
variable b: -1

variable lat:
variable b: 0

variable lat:
variable b: 1
```

I tried SET without /A of course, I tried that within FOR where variable %%b was a string from a file and it worked normally, but just here when variabl %%b is a changing number it does not work.

If you would have any suggestion, please tell me. Of couse I can use just %%b to diplay what I want, but since this is a part of larger scritp, to make it more readable, I would like to but the vaules to approproate variable.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980718/cmd-for-loop-does-not-hold-set-a-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. Try with the below:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo off
for /L %%b in (-1,1,1) do (
    set /A _lat=%%b
    echo variable lat: !_lat!
    echo variable b: %%b
    echo:
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the output of `SET /?` in a console.  You need to enable and use *delayed environment variable expansion* for this to work.  Here's the relevant snippet from the `help set`:

> Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been
>   added.  This support is always disabled by default, but may be
>   enabled/disabled via the /V command line switch to CMD.EXE.  See CMD /?
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
>   the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line
>   of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
>   demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements
>   is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically
>   includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the
>   IF inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
>   "after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
>   will not work as expected:
>
> ```
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory,
>   but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found.
>   Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the
>   FOR statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty.
>   So the actual FOR loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
> for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
>   execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
>   examples could be written as follows to work as intended:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
>
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved the problem. I had no idea that something like "delayed environment variable expansion". So for the next time, I will really read helps..